# Android Push Notification whenever a row of a database table is updated at server side

Tags: android, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am making an android app using `WebView`. My website is designed using `PHP` and database used is `mySQL`.

Is there any way so that whenever a new row will be added into a database table at `server side` a `push notification` will be generated ?

Suppose my database contains **ID** and **Location**.
There are values like :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>    <kbd>**`Location`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`USA`</kbd>     
<kbd>`2`</kbd>     <kbd>`India`</kbd>   
<kbd>`3`</kbd>     <kbd>`UK`</kbd>

Now, a new record is added :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>    <kbd>**`Location`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`USA`</kbd>     
<kbd>`2`</kbd>     <kbd>`India`</kbd>   
<kbd>`3`</kbd>     <kbd>`UK`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>     <kbd>`Germany`</kbd>

I want a push notification in my android app like that : `A new record has been added`

Can anyone please help me ?

> NB: I don't have any idea about **Google Cloud Messaging**
>
> Supporting link or tutorial or document how to use `Google Cloud Messaging` will be very helpful .
>   If the question is duplicate,please provide me the previous links

Comment: If I recall correctly Google wants everyone to use Firebase, which includes Notifications, and its [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) mentions DB integration too. Hope this helps!